# Video streaming via Gstreamer

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I try to check video rtp stream on my Windows OS computer using command on server:

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location = d:/TestVideos/lama.mp4 ! qtdemux ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.162 port=6001

Then I try to catch stream:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=6001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

I see such a picture in the console:

[image]

And thats all. When the video ends server window automatically closing.

But if try to use the testvideosrc, everything works good.

Server side:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, framerate=20/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.162 port=6001

Client side:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=6001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

[image]

Unfortunately I can't find mistake... It would be great if anyone help to find it. Thank you.

Comment: I encountered too such an issue on headless systems. Try using `glimagesink` or `ximagesink`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as well :

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location = d:/TestVideos/lama.mp4 ! qtdemux ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse !rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.162 port=6001
```

And at receiving side

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=6001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" !  rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Below are my commands on a single board computer - Freescale imx6 (for reference)

```
gst-launch-1.0 –gst-debug=0 imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video1 fps-n=30 capture-mode=4 ! imxvpuenc_h264 bitrate=1000
 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.11.11 port=5001

gst-launch-1.0 –gst-debug=0 udpsrc port=5001 ! $CAPS ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! 
autovideosink sync=true
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works!! If I get you right, it's rtp protocol via udp? It's not legasy technology today? May be I should try use http protocol? And how can I buffering video stream does gstreamer have any options for this? Thank you again!

Comment: accept the answer if it solved the issue. for the other questions, I am not sure if I understand your previous comment, you have to be more elaborate. Yes it is RTP over UDP in my case, because I am streaming from a client to source over wireless network.  Do you mean a smooth video when you talk about buffering? You can use element `queue` for that.